# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while generating netcdf file

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, netcdf, sift

## :::::::::::::::::::::::SIFT_FEATURE Method:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

def sift_features(filename, inputs):

```
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sift = cv2.SIFT(70)
kp = sift.detect(gray,None)
img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp)
cv2.imwrite(filename +'_sift_keypoints.jpg',img)

index = []
for point in kp:
    temp = (point.pt, point.size, point.angle, point.response, point.octave, point.class_id) 

    index.append(temp)

        counter=[]
    for val in index:
        for ele in val:
        counter.append(ele)

    inputs.append(counter)

return inputs
```

#::::::::::::::Pass each file to Sift_features():::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
for lineFilename in lineFilenames:
#   print "LINE FILE NAME", lineFilename
    if not (options.labelsOnly):
            if options.features:
            print "FILE NAME ---------------------------------- :", lineFilename
                lineLength = sift_features(lineFilename, inputs)
        if options.wholeBoard:
            fileLength+= lineLength
        else:
            seqLengths.append(lineLength)
```

## ::::::: Creating netcdf File :::::::::::::::::

```
ncfile =netcdf_helpers.NetCDFFile(ncFilename, 'w')
if not (options.labelsOnly):
    netcdf_helpers.createNcDim(ncfile,'numSeqs',len(seqLengths))
    netcdf_helpers.createNcDim(ncfile,'numTimesteps',len(inputs))
    netcdf_helpers.createNcDim(ncfile,'inputPattSize',len(inputs[0]))
netcdf_helpers.createNcDim(ncfile,'numLabels',len(labels))
netcdf_helpers.createNcStrings(ncfile,'labels',labels,      ('numLabels','maxLabelLength'),'labels')
netcdf_helpers.createNcStrings(ncfile,'targetStrings',targetStrings,('numSeqs','maxTargStringLength'),'target strings')
if not (options.labelsOnly):
    netcdf_helpers.createNcStrings(ncfile,'seqTags',seqTags,('numSeqs','maxSeqTagLength'),'sequence tags')
    netcdf_helpers.createNcVar(ncfile,'seqLengths',seqLengths,'i',('numSeqs',),'sequence lengths')
    netcdf_helpers.createNcVar(ncfile,'inputs',inputs,'f',('numTimesteps','inputPattSize'),'input patterns')
print "writing data to", ncFilename
ncfile.close()
```

The Sift Features indicated 70 points in image and at each point

```
temp = (point.pt, point.size, point.angle, point.response, point.octave, point.class_id)
```

is calculated. I want to pass feature values to netcdf file by

```
netcdf_helpers.createNcVar(ncfile,'seqLengths',seqLengths,'i',('numSeqs',),'sequence lengths')
```

statement. The seqLengths variable has feature values of all images. But when I tried to generate netcdf file it stucked with the error as mentioned below.

```
creating netcdf dimension: numSeqs 1335574
creating netcdf dimension: numTimesteps 20
creating netcdf dimension: inputPattSize 210
creating netcdf dimension: numLabels 29
writing strings labels
creating netcdf dimension: maxLabelLength 6
creating netcdf variable labels
dimensions ('numLabels', 'maxLabelLength')
(29, 6)
writing strings targetStrings
creating netcdf dimension: maxTargStringLength 115
creating netcdf variable targetStrings
dimensions ('numSeqs', 'maxTargStringLength')
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know that error occurred during passing feature values to netcdf file by seqLengths varriable. The feature values are in the form [[(1,2,4,5),(6,7,8,9,10),(11,12,13,14,15)],[(16,17,8,19,20),(21,22,23,24,25)]]

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Since Python is a managed runtime, a Segmentation fault can always be considered a bug in the runtime or one of the libraries that include native code. The library is more likely in this case, so I would recommend bringing it up on their mailing list or whatever forum they have.

Comment: Of course, both here and on the mailing list, you need to post a [**complete**, verifiable example (preferably minimal)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you posted isn't enough to be run and debugged. You should also state exact version of python and all involved libraries—bugs like this can manifest differently in different versions.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and netcdf_helpers.py (https://github.com/jpuigcerver/rnnlib/blob/master/utils/netcdf_helpers.py) for generating feature file

Comment: the code is too lengthy to post here.

Comment: "2.7" is far from "complete version". The netcdf_helpers are not that relevant as it is just a bit of python code, but the `Scientific` library it uses is. If the example is too long, you need to reduce it (that's why I [_linked_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the how to).

Comment: IMO the best NetCDF library for Python is python-netcdf4 from Unidata, I suggest just trying this https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/
And of course, if problem is in netcdf creation, limit Your code to just NetCDF creation with some arbitrary data.